# Cofinite topology on infinite set coming from a metric?

Tags: general-topology

How do I go about proving that cofinite topology on an infinite set does not come from a metric?

I was thinking about proving it on $\mathbb{N}$ first then generalize it on any infinite set. Because for any infinite set I can find a canonical bijection of $\mathbb{N}$ embedded in it and I reduce to the subspace topology on that copy of $\mathbb{N}$.

Is this thought process correct? Thank you.

Comment: Hint: the metric topology is Hausdorff.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Hint:** Note that every two cofinite sets have a cofinite intersection. Therefore the topology cannot separate two points by disjoint open sets.

Comment: Ok, what you mention is called $T_2$ right? Cofinite topology on infinite sets satisfy $T_1$ but not $T_2$ right?

Comment: @mezhang: Yes, $T_2$, or Hausdorff, as JHF mentioned in the comment.